# Is there a closed form of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, closed-form

The sequence is  $\frac{1}{1}$ , $\frac{1}{2}$ , $\frac{2}{1}$ , $\frac{1}{3}$ , $\frac{2}{2}$ , $\frac{3}{1}$ , $\frac{1}{4}$ , $\frac{2}{3}$ , $\frac{3}{2}$ , $\frac{4}{1}$ , ...
                   and I need to find n th..

Here's my approach..

I bound them with who has same sum of denominator and numerator.

So $\frac{1}{1}$ is set_1 .

$\frac{1}{2}$ , $\frac{2}{1}$ are set_2..

$\frac{1}{3}$ , $\frac{2}{2}$ , $\frac{3}{1}$ are set_3 .

$\frac{1}{4}$ , $\frac{2}{3}$ , $\frac{3}{2}$ , $\frac{4}{1}$ are set_4 and so on..

If I suppose that n is in set_K , I can conclude n th number is $$ \frac{1+( (n-1)-\sum_{i=1}^K (i-1) ) }{ K - ( (n-1)-\sum_{i=1}^K (i-1) ) } $$

( because set_K starts with $\frac{1}{K}$ and n is ( n - $\sum_{i=1}^K (i-1)$ ) th member of set_K.. )

As a result my conclusion is $$\frac{2n-(K-1)K}{K(K+1) - 2(n-1) }$$ but I don't know the relationship between n and K..

Is there anyone to help me? I really want to know.. :(

Comment: Can you put this all in mathjax mode please?

Comment: [Faray sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) might be relevant.

Comment: Reminds me of a project Euler problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break the sequence in groups of $N$ terms with $N=1,2,3,\dots$ of the form
$$\frac{k}{N+1-k}\quad \text {for $k=1,2,\dots ,N$}.$$
So the first $N-1$ groups have $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}i=\binom{N}{2}$ terms. 
Now, given $n$, there is a unique $N$ such that $\binom{N}{2}<n\leq \binom{N+1}{2}$, which means that the $n$-term is in the $N$-th group and it is equal to
$\frac{k}{N+1-k}$ with $k=n-\binom{N}{2}$. For an explicit formula solve $\binom{N}{2}<n\leq \binom{N+1}{2}$ with respect to $N$:
$$N=\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment :). By the way .. How to get N from $\sum_{i=2}^N (i-1) $ < n <= $\sum_{i=1}^N i $ ?

Comment: @KYRIN Start by solving $\binom{N}{2}<n$ that is the quadratic $N^2-N-2n<0$.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$-th term can be expressed as ${\large{\frac{a}{b}}}$, where 
\begin{align*}
a&=n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\\[4pt]
b&=k+2-a\\[4pt]
k&=
\left\lfloor
{
\frac
{
\left\lfloor
\sqrt{8n-7}
\right\rfloor
-1
}
{2}
}
\right\rfloor\\[4pt]
\end{align*}